# Find difference between two consecutive rows of same column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I'm having a situation where I need to calculate the difference between two consecutive rows of same column. Here is my table named 'orders' structure.

```
orderid   type     productsales
1002      Order    120         
1002      Refund   -35   
1003      Order    199           
1003      Refund   -50            
1004      Order    245
1005      Order    80
```

Now, what I want to Select only those records where the 'productsales' difference between the same `orderids` of order type 'Order' & 'Refund' is greater than 0

Comment: 1. `GROUP BY` 2. `MAX` and `MIN` 3. Nested query

Comment: can you please show this by mysql query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select orderid
from orders
group by orderid
having sum(case when `type` = 'Order' then productsales else 0 end) +
       sum(case when `type` = 'Refund' then productsales else 0 end) > 0
```

You need to subtract the values from another. But since you stored the `-` in the refund I used `+`.

Comment: Juregen d, I've really became your fan. You are such a genius. In last 24 hours, you solved my two complex problems. A big THANKSSS to you :)

Comment: To be honest, I was willing Juergen to post his answer on my question :)

Comment: You are welcome (But don't put my answer in your question :-) )

Comment: No way.. All credit is yours you GENIUS. Just waiting for the time delay to end. So, I can accept your answer :)